# gnuplot arrowstyle variable command not respected

Tags: vector, colors, gnuplot

I'm trying to color vectors in gnuplot
I have a data file like

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 2
```

where the last column is to be used to read an arrow style using the "arrowstyle variable" command as in:

```
set style arrow 1 linecolor rgb "red"
set style arrow 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
set zrange [-1:1]
splot 'c:\vector.txt'using 1:2:3:4:5:6 with vectors arrowstyle variable
```

however, the vectors are all black. That is gnuplot isn't reading the style from the data file. I can get this to work if I put the data in two files not not in one.

Comment: I'm getting `warning: arrowstyle 0 not found`

Comment: You need one more column, `using 1:2:3:4:5:6:7`

Comment: Thanks, but adding the :7 to the using statement doesn't do the trick, either and, as choroba finds, I get the arrowstyle 0 not found error. Not only that, but when I orbit the resulting graph redraws itself multiple times over itself.

Comment: `splot 'vector.txt'using 1:2:3:4:5:6:7 with vectors arrowstyle variable` works for me without generating an error message. This is on gnuplot 5.2.2; which version are you using? Are you sure you don't have a line in your data file that has a `0` in the seventh column?

Comment: the actual data is 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 1
0 0 0 -1 -1 1 1
0 0 0 -1 1 -1 1
0 0 0 1 -1 -1 2 and I have version 5 patch level 3 it says. Sorry about the formatting; I can't seem to enter my own carriage returns without it closing this box.

Comment: The problem is resolved! I downloaded the latest version (5.2 patch level 4) from 1 Jun 2018 just now  and it works fine. But thanks for looking.